# A week around Europe

Tags: knowledge, visual, geography, language, sequence

I've recently returned from a week of travelling around Europe, visiting a different town or city in a different country on each day, choosing my destinations according to an underlying pattern. I've plotted the first six places I visited on the map below; I need you to tell me: **Which UK town or city did I visit on the last day of my trip?**

Moreover, **can you identify each town or city I visited, and the order in which I visited them?**

---

<sup>'Checksums' to help you ensure you have correctly identified the mapped towns/cities (using spellings as per the English-language version of Google Maps):</sup>
 <sup>- Their name lengths (in increasing order) are 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, and 15;</sup>
 <sup>- The last letters of their names (in alphabetical order) are: E, E, H, L, N, and O.</sup>
<sup>NB Ignore all accent marks. If multiple options exist, *go big*...</sup>

[image: Map of Europe with 6 destinations marked]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On your last day of your trip, I think you visited

> Sunderland

Your method for determining the location you visit is

> The first three letters of the location match the first three letters of the day of the week in the language of the country you visit.

The places and order in which you visited them were

> **MON**CHENGLADBACH, Germany on **MON**TAG (Monday).
>  **MAR**SEILLE, France on **MAR**DI (Tuesday).
>  **WOE**RDEN, Netherlands on **WOE**NSDAG (Wednesday).
>  **TOR**NIO, Finland on **TOR**STAI (Thursday).
>  **VEN**ICE, Italy on **VEN**ERDI (Friday).
>  **SAB**ADELL, Spain on **SAB**ADO (Saturday).

So you will last visit

> **SUN**DERLAND on **SUN**DAY

Comment: Correction: rot13(Gbeavb, Svaynaq ba rvgure n Gbefgnv be Gbefqnt, obgu jbex!)

Comment: @Jafe My deepest apologies.

Comment: This is entirely correct. Well found :)

Comment: But it's M**ö**nchengladbach :/

Comment: @kopaka: Read the question properly